# Run shell command with many arguments

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, string-interpolation

I have a very long command with many arguments, and somehow it's not working the way it should work. The following `knife` command will connect to remote vCenter and create a VM called `node1`. How do I wrap the following command and run inside ruby? Am I doing something wrong?

```
var_name = 'node1'
var_folder = 'folder1'
var_datastore = 'datastore1'
var_template_file = 'template_foo'
var_template = 'foo'
var_location = 'US'

cmd = 'knife vsphere vm clone var_name --dest-folder var_folder --datastore var_datastore --template-file var_template_file --template var_template -f var_location'

system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'shellwords'
cmd = "knife vsphere vm clone #{var_name.shellescape} --dest-folder #{var_folder.shellescape} --datastore #{var_datastore.shellescape} --template-file #{var_template_file.shellescape} --template #{var_template.shellescape} -f #{var_location.shellescape}"
```

In your specific case it would work even without `shellescape`, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not resolved in your command. Try using #{var_name} etc for all variables in the varaible cmd